# OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility Hangs on Creating Configuration

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

Trying to migrate TFS to Visual Studio Online. I have everything all set as per the website instructions. I get to Creating Configuration in progress. It might take 4-5 minutes... and it just stops. Nothing in the log files. No errors and none of the side links work.

Update: In the ObsHub.log

06/11/2015 09:44:41,509 ERROR [main] (com.opshub.JSON.QuartzIntializationServlet) - Error while trying to install license VisualStudio.lic
com.opshub.license.exception.LicenseException: License with key 252 is already installed
    at com.opshub.license.install.LicenseInstaller.checkDuplicateLicense(LicenseInstaller.java:114)
    at com.opshub.license.install.LicenseInstaller.installLicense(LicenseInstaller.java:66)
    at com.opshub.JSON.QuartzIntializationServlet.registerLicFile(QuartzIntializationServlet.java:289)
    at com.opshub.JSON.QuartzIntializationServlet.installLicenses(QuartzIntializationServlet.java:265)
    at com.opshub.JSON.QuartzIntializationServlet.contextInitialized(QuartzIntializationServlet.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3843)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:829)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:718)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1147)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
06/11/2015 09:56:23,644 ERROR [http-8989-1] (com.opshub.eai.tfs.common.TFSUtility) - Not able to delete file O:\1434030982580.txt

Comment: It probably stuck in processing, what do that logs indicate? (You can find them at C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs )

Comment: Added an update with the log information in my post

Comment: Hi, these both errors do not impact your current issue. Is something printed in the OpsHubTFSService.log ?